# Spectrum of spectrum in the stable homotopy category

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Let $\mathcal{E}=(E_0,E_1,\cdots)$ be an $S^1$-spectrum. Define $\Sigma \mathcal{E}$ to be the spectrum with $(\Sigma \mathcal{E})_n=E_{n+1}$. Then, consider the spectrum $\tilde{\mathcal{E}} =(\mathcal{E}, \Sigma\mathcal{E}, \Sigma^2 \mathcal{E},\cdots)$. The bonding maps are maps of spectra induced by those of $\mathcal{E}$, $S^1\wedge E_n\to E_{n+1}$.

Can $\tilde{\mathcal{E}}$ be considered as an object in $SH$, the stable homotopy category of  $S^1$-spectra? If yes,  is there an equivalence $\mathcal{E}\simeq \tilde{\mathcal{E}} $ in $SH$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Try to show as much of your work as possible, so people here know exactly how to provide help.

Comment: The answer is yes to both, if you make sense of things correctly. There are a couple of ways to do that: (1) you could interpret that list of spaces as presenting a spectrum as a homotopy colimit of suspension spectra, and if you compute the corresponding homotopy colimit of spectra you get with your E-tilde construction you get an equivalent thing, (2) you could take the spanier whitehead category, and the spanier whitehead category of a stable category doesn't spits out what you started with.

Comment: @DylanWilson Thank you for the comment. Could you explain what you mean by _presenting a spectrum as a homotopy colimit of suspension spectra_? Do you mean that the E-tilde is equivalent in the homotopy category to the spectrum whose n-th object is the `colim_m \Omega^m E_{n+m}` where Omega is the loop space functor? Given the naivity of my questions, you must be able to understand that I am new to these things. Thus, any reference will also be of great help.